# язык пагинации modx revolution

Tags: modx

Привет,

Нужна помощи в переводе пагинации на modx revolution на немецком сайте.
Пагинация работает нормально, но вместо **"Zuerst"** выводиться **"Первая"** и вместо **"Letzte"** выводиться **"Последняя"**. Где можно поменять язык пагинации?
Пагинация сделана, насколько понял пакетом "pdotools".

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdopage_first`, `pdopage_last` и `pdopage_more` переопределяются через `управление словарями` в админке модикса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да есть такое, есть уже и готовая нем версия в блоке ("Язык"), можно и выбрать ее, но как ее сохранить, чтобы оно применилось?

Comment: После изменения содержимого поля - щелчок в любом другом месте. После потери фокуса поле сохраняется автоматически. Сначала появляется красный треугольник сигнализирующий о том что сохранение началось. Как он пропадет - значит сохранилось успешно.

Comment: В том то и дело что ничего не происходит.

Comment: я тоже прочитал об этом, но никаких действий нет(

Comment: MODX Revolution
MODX Revolution 2.5.0-pl - такая версия - может в ней проблема?

Comment: я понял вы говорите о `pdopage_first, pdopage_last и pdopage_more`, но у меня они уже готовые есть - я выбираю язык `de` и где мне это сохранить и как вывести в шаблоне?

Comment: Нет. Версия новая. Я так понимаю Вы пытаетесь изменить поле "язык" вместо того чтобы изменять переводы в поле "значение"? Если так - то делаете совершенно неправильные вещи. Если вы изначально не меняли локаль сайта с ru на de, то беполезно менять на другие языки. Правьте русский.

Comment: Походу локаль не поменян. Спасибо